# How to render different pages from components fully in angular?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, routes

I want to build a website with different pages that are routed via the url. But the background of the component is rendered and downsized some px over the mainbackground from the app.html. It worked a little bit with Renderer2, but with that, I can't include my css file.

[There are also two scrollingbars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhtJD.png)

**component.html** (it is also if I just set a black background)

```
<div style="background:black; height: 100vh">Hello</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-engineering',
  templateUrl: './engineering.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./engineering.component.css']
})
export class EngineeringComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**css is empty**

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NotfoundComponent } from './notfound/notfound.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
import { EngineeringComponent } from './engineering/engineering.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NotfoundComponent,
    EngineeringComponent,
    IndexComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'engineering',
        component: EngineeringComponent
      }, {
        path: 'index',
        component: IndexComponent
      }, {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/index',
        pathMatch: 'full' ,
      }, {
        path: '**',
        component: NotfoundComponent
      },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular';
}
```